# Calculating Chi Square on Spark with sequence of pair of features

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, chi-squared

Actually it is a few days that I'm stuck on this challenge and I wanted to know your ideas about it. I have a big dataframe in pyspark with around 150 features. Each row belongs to one person and the value of each cell is either 0 or 1. I am interested in knowing is there any correlation between these features or not. Because these features are Categorical, I chose Chi Square Independence test.

For each pair I created the contingency table by using Crosstab and then convert the corsstab output to a dense matrix and calculate the p-value for each pair. For small scale it works, but for big data volume the code keeps running for long time and it is not efficient in my opinion. The problem is since I need the combination of all features it increases the calculation size exponentially.

What approach do you suggest to do this job with better performance?

```
def calculate_chi(df, col1, col2):
   test = df.crosstab(col2, col1) 
   vals = test.rdd.map(lambda x:[x[1],x[2]]).flatMap(lambda y: y).collect()
   Matrix = Matrices.dense(2, 2, vals)
   return Statistics.chiSqTest(Matrix).pValue

if __name__=="__main__":
   spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
   df=spark.read.option("header",True).csv("s3a://*.csv")
   df = df.select(selected_cols)
   data = []
   cols =  combinations(df.columns,2)
   for c in cols:
      data.append((str(c), calculate_chi(df, c[0],c[1])))
   df_results = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["feature_pair","pvalue"])
   df_results.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').options(header='true').save("s3a://chiSqTest")
```

Comment: You make only pairwise tests so the size should quadratic not exponential. That being said, you can compute full frequency table in a single sweep (should be feasible with 150 features) or partial frequency tables for each feature (one vs rest) and compute each  χ2 in parallel. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the problem lies at line number 3 of the function `calculate_chi`. You used a matrix representation that is not distributed, so the driver node is a bottleneck for your algorithm both in terms of memory and that of CPU. I would suggest you consider using distributed matrix representations from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.package). Since χ<sup>2</sup> test can be conducted for each column independently, I think you should be able to better utilize the power of your cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Elior. Yes, It makes sense. I will try this approach and let you know the result.

Comment: The problem is that chiSqTest only accept dense matrix. Moreover, this matrix is tiny (2x2) and re-partitioning is not useful. I seems that somehow I should force spark to run calculate_chi in distributed mode. Nevertheless, I thought YARN was doing this automatically, isn't it? https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-statistics.html

Comment: @Moohebat, there are several versions of chi-square done distributively already. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.stat.ChiSquareTest$ is a dataframe API. Also there are RDD level APIs in `mllib`.

Comment: Thanks @Elior, I am aware of that. If you study my code you can understand my problem better.